# How to read a text file that is already in use (Windows C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, file-io, windows-7, share

I have an application that creates a text log file using an `std::ofstream` using `std::ofstream::app` to create it. This application is writing logs often, sometimes only milliseconds apart.

I want to write a second application that reads in and analyses this log file *whilst the first application is still writing to it*

I have some working code, using `ifstream`, that loads & processes a standalone text log file, but this code fails when I try to use it on the text log file that is currently being written to with "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

How can I adjust my log reader to allow me to read the text file currently being written to (which Notepad++ is able to do on the same file!)?

Comment: It should be passed by default, but have you tried passing `_SH_DENYNO` as the third argument to your `ofstream` constructor / `open` function? Note that this is a windows-only extension.

Comment: I hadn't, but have now. And after working out that I needed to use SH_DENYNO (without the _ as my "share.h" defines it that way) I found that this does indeed work. Can you put your comment in as an answer for me to tick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows you can pass a third parameter to the stream constructors / `open` to allow sharing, e.g.

```
std::ofstream of("path", of.app, _SH_DENYNO);
```

`(int)ios_base::_Openprot` is passed by default which is an `enum` set to `_OPENPROT`, which is in turn defined as `_SH_DENYNO` so it should already work without specifying the flag, I'm not really sure why it doesn't in your case, have you tried following the definitions in VS or debugging the code?

reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1et11xw(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kexhtshc(v=vs.110).aspx