# Filesystem WinAPI vs std::filestystem

Tags: winapi, filesystems, c++17

I'm porting very old project to c++17 (atomics, mutexes, UTF conversions, etc), and faced with CreateFile parameters problem.

Let's say

```
::CreateFileA(newFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
```

Is there 100% equivalent code using std::filesystem permissions and other stuff? So far I can't see something similar to FILE_SHARE_READ or GENERIC_WRITE.

**UP:** We need this for Linux port.

Comment: The functions and classes in [the `std::filesystem` namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) doesn't really deal with files like that, reading and writing them. That's what you use the file streams for (e.g. `std::ifstream` for input-only files, or `std::ofstream` for output-only files). Besides the linked `std::filesystem` reference, and that whole site, I suggest you get [a few good books about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read.

Comment: For file access I've never used the C++ infrastructure. Too many features exposed by the Windows API have no equivalent in C++ (e.g. `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`, ACL's, ADS', asynchronous I/O, sparse files, etc.). An RAII wrapper for the file `HANDLE` is as far as I'd go in terms of moving file access to C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it deals. Look at [std::filesystem::perms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/perms). I know, that I have to create file using std::stream, but [std::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) has options for permissions and properties

Comment: `GENERIC_WRITE` is the open-mode, not a permission, and as such there's no equivalent in `std::filesystem`. Its equivalence is the modes in [`std::ios_base::openmode`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode). With the standard library you can't set file permissions when opening a file-stream. you have to do it in two separate actions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - `GENERIC_WRITE` this is not open mode, but exactly permission. it mapped to concrete object type permission. in case file - it mapped to `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE`

Comment: @RbMm I think you better [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). The `dwDesiredAccess` argument is `GENERIC_READ`, `GENERIC_WRITE` or a bitwise OR of both. It's the open-mode, saying what your program want to do with the file, reading from the file or writing to it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - no, what is "open mode" ?! this is exactly access. it nothing say about what your program want to do with the file. this is permission

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and *The dwDesiredAccess argument is GENERIC_READ, GENERIC_WRITE or a bitwise OR of both* - this is possible values. but we can use and any [`another`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258116(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @RbMm Okay, then show me a program that passes `GENERIC_WRITE` as `dwDesiredAccess` and then tries to *read* from the file. `GENERIC_WRITE` is analogous to the [open-mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) `out`, while `GENERIC_READ` is analogous to `in`. Or the old C [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) modes `"w"` and `"r"`, respectively. It may be *checked* against the filesystem permisions, but it's not otherwise related to them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - i speak about windows api. no any "open-mode" here conception. exist `ACCESS_MASK` value that determines the requested access to the object. we say to windows which access we request for object. which we will be do (if any) with file - this is absolute another question. if program not request `FILE_READ_DATA` but try read from file - it got access denied. but so what ?

Comment: For the sharing flags like `FILE_SHARE_READ` you can use the 3rd constructor parameter of the standard file streams, which is a Microsoft extension. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25178473/7571258). You could derive from the standard stream classes to abstract the Windows specifics away for your Linux port. Another option, if you need even more control: Use [Boost.Iostreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, @zett42!